# keep variables with a doop loop sas

Tags: loops, sas

Is there any form to keep variables with a doop loop in data step?
will be something as:

```
data test;
input id aper_f_201501 aper_f_201502 aper_f_201503 aper_f_201504 
aper_f_201505 aper_f_201506;
datalines;
1 0 1 2 3 5 7
2 -1 5 4 8 7 9
;
run;

%macro test;
%let date = '01Jul2015'd;

data test2;
set test(keep=do i = 1 to 3;
                 aper_f_%sysfunc(intnx(month,&date,-i,begin),yymmn6.);
              end;)
run;
%mend;
%test;
```

I need to iterate several dates.
Thank you very much.

Comment: No, but you can use shortcut references if you have a common prefix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use macro `%do` loop instead of the data step `do` loop, which is not going to be valid in the middle of a dataset option. Also do not generate those extra semi-colons into the middle of your dataset options. And do include a semi-colon to end your SET statement.

```
%macro test;
%local i date;
%let date = '01Jul2015'd;

data test2;
  set test(keep=
%do i = 1 %to 3;
  aper_f_%sysfunc(intnx(month,&date,-i,begin),yymmn6.)
%end;
  );
run;
%mend;
%test;
```

Comment: Wooow It works well @Tom Thank you very much. Missing % in to and macro variable i. Why declare i and date as local macro variable? Without local word works well too.

Comment: @SandraGuerrero It's good practice to define them as local, to ensure there isn't a collision with a global macro variable.  It's not necessary for it to work, but if you have a `&i` or `&date` in your main program it could collide and cause an issue.

Comment: Ok I understand you. @Joe Thank you.

Comment: I updated the answer to include the missing `%` to the `%to` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the colon shortcut to reference variables with the same prefix, anything in front of the colon will be kept.

```
keep ID aper_f_2015: ;
```

There's also a hyphen when you have sequential lists

```
keep ID aper_f_201501-aper_f_201512;
```

You can use a macro but not sure it adds a lot of value here.